# djangocms-snippet which contains {% %} doesnot show up as placeholder content

Tags: django, django-cms

I am trying to make my footer a editable from frontend.. using placeholder and inserting footer snippet.

yet, my footer snippet contains django template language

e.g.

```
<a href="{% url terms_conditions %}">Terms and Conditions</a>
```

as a result, the placeholder content is not showing up, if i remove the django specific things

```
<a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a>
```

it is working.

how can I make it work with django reverse url?

I could have given hard coded path but i want the path translatable so i need to reverse by url's name.

Comment: is there `terms_conditions` in `urls.py` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've got you right, just create custom tag and store templates in database:

```
from django.template import RequestContext, Template
@register.simple_tag
def footer(request):
    snippet = Snippet.object.get(name='footer')
    template = Template(snippet.html)
    return template.render(RequestContext(request))

{% footer request %}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this syntax:

```
{% url 'terms_conditions' as the_url %}
<a href="{{ the_url }}">Terms and Conditions</a>
```

Comment: this will not work since the snippet doesnot support django template tags.

Answer (score 0):

use [smartsnippets](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-cms-smartsnippets)

These has the capability of rendering django tags